# get_object_or_404 always yields 404 in Django

Tags: python, django

So this is my `urls.py`

```
url(r'^file/(?P<filename>.*)$', 'notendur.views.file', name="file"),
```

And this is my `views.py`

```
@login_required
def file(request, filename):
    file = get_object_or_404(Document, user=request.user, filename=filename)
    return sendfile(request, file.docfile.path)
```

And this is my `models.py`

```
fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.UPLOAD_ROOT)

class Document(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    upload_path = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=_upload_path, storage=fs)
    options = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def get_upload_path(self,filename):
        return "uploads/"+str(self.user.id) + '/' + str(date.today()) + '/' + filename
```

So my problem is that, even though the path to the file is correct, I always get a 404 error. I suspect it's because there's something wrong with my get_object_or_404 function.

EDT__:

The files are actually in `file/uploads/<primary_key>/<upload_date>/` ! So sorry for leaving that out. What kind of regular expression captures that kind of link?

Comment: Drop in and inspect the sql query being sent, maybe the filename that the function is trying to fetch is wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be correct, though, if I can see the file in the correct folder and the browser says it tried to reach that exact file?

Comment: Minor nitpick: you have `filename = models.CharField(... blank=False ...)` in the model but `(?P<filename>.*)` in the URL, which allows `filename == ''` for the URL `file/`.

Comment: Side note - change your local variable name from `file` to something else. It conflicts with the view name.

Comment: Actually, I think `file` is a built-in function in Python, which you're masking. BTW, your edit makes no sense. the path you give starts with `file/uploads/` but `file/` is the URL and `uploads/` is the path on disk.

Comment: Also, you have `upload_path = models...` but use `upload_to=_upload_path` in the `FileField`. You don't define `_upload_path` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a queryset :

```
queryset = Document.objects.filter(user=request.user, filename=filename)
get_object_or_404(queryset)
```

You can also try to print some values to try to identify the problem :

```
print request.user
print filename
```

Also, you accept empty string in your URL as filename (by using *). Why not using "+"? :

```
url(r'^file/(?P<filename>.+)$', 'notendur.views.file', name="file"),
```

For information in case you need it, a list of references :

```
# Regular references:
# . any char
# ^ start of string
# $ end of string
# * 0 or more of preceding
# + 1 or more of preceding
# ? 0 or 1 of preceding
# (?!..) matches when it doesnt match ..
# *? 0 or more, minimal match
# +? 1 or more, minimal match
# {m} exactly m of preceding
# {m,n} between m to n of preceding
# [..] eg. [abc],[a-z],[0-9a-z]
# [^..] matches if doesn't match [..]
# (..) groups what's inside
# (?=..) matches .. but doesn't consume it
# \d [0-9] (decimal digit)
# \D [^0-9] (non-digit)
# \w [a-zA-Z0-9_] (alphanumeric)
# \W [^a-zA-Z0-9_] (non-alphanumeric)
# \s [ \t\n\r\f\v] (whitespace)
# \S [^ \t\n\r\f\v] (non-whitespace)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `filename` is correct, then it seems the `user` does not match. This view only allows access to the user owning the file; is this correct? If so, you should really be returning a 403:

```
@login_required
def file(request, filename):
    file = get_object_or_404(Document, filename=filename)
    if file.user != request.user:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return sendfile(request, file.docfile.path)
```

---

Let's say the user has ID 5, and they try to access `file/test_file` which was uploaded on June 30, 2014. Then `filename == 'test_file'` and the matching record should have the following fields:

```
filename: "test_file"
upload_path: "uploads/5/2014-06-30/test_file"
user: <User with id: 5>
docfile.path: "uploads/5/2014-06-30/test_file"
```

Does this match up with what you see on disk and/or in the database?

Comment: That's much cleaner, thanks. But I am still getting a 404. Mustn't there be an error in relaying the information to the function? The function itself seems so simple that there can't be anything else wrong with it.

Comment: Oh, I forgot a major piece of information. Appended in OP.